# Calculating Upper bound of a function

Tags: asymptotics

If T(N) = T(sqrt(N)) + 1
and T(1) = 1

then what is the upper bound i.e O(N) for this function?

sqrt(N) => square root of N

Comment: See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). What difficulty are you having with this exercise?